# Unable to add custom input to 3rd party symfony bundle

Tags: php, css, symfony, orocommerce

I have started to learn how to customize a theme for `orocommerce`, so far I have successfully changed the logo, but I have a problem with `css` loading. 
I have followed this tutorial: https://oroinc.com/orocommerce/doc/current/dev-guide/theme/layout but my css still won't load

Here is my bundle structure.

[image]

and here are my assets.yml file. 
[image]

Is there something that I am missing?

Thank you

Comment: share your code plz -- seems your path is not correct...

Comment: your path should be `css/frontend/custom_frontend.css`

Answer (score 0):

documentation that you use related to admin part of application.
To customize front store part please read next documentation https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/LayoutBundle/Resources/doc/config_definition.md#assets

So, css styles from `Resources/config/oro/assets.yml` will not applied for front store part. To add new styles you need to add styles in Layout theme folder like in `https://github.com/oroinc/orocommerce/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/ProductBundle/Resources/views/layouts/default/config/assets.yml`.